# Accessing Json and httpclient jars in browser using javaFx

Tags: java, json, javafx, jnlp, liveconnect

In my application i am loading javafx application in browser using java Live connect api, and accessing the fx application through jsp using dtjava.js as referred in http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm .
With reference of fx application(Id="app") i am accessing the fx main class methods by using html/javascript buttons using

```
function javafxEmbed() {
            dtjava.embed(
            {
                url : 'abc.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                id:'app',
                width : 550,
                height : 344,
                jnlp_content : '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'

            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            } 
        );
```

app.methodname() till it is fine.

But i am not able to access the the methods if those are accessing

> JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

(All jar's are signed-in)
I am facing the problem while accessing json jars(json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar ) or org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar from the broser html button).

Getting respnse in java debug console like

[image]
Any Suggessions?

Comment: *"Any Suggessions?"*  Post the text in the console, rather than an unreadable (unindexable) image.

Comment: I'm starting to regret using JavaFX.